# Change checkbox icon for a custom checkbox made with bootrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

I'm using this [bootstrap custom checkbox](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/beautify-checkboxes-amp-radio-input-group-addons) and I wanna change the icon with jQuery. Right now the checkbox is changing only when I click on it.

```
$(function () {
    $('.input-group-addon.beautiful').each(function () {

        var $widget = $(this),
            $input = $widget.find('input'),
            type = $input.attr('type');
        settings = {
            checkbox: {
                on: {icon: 'fa fa-check-circle-o'},
                off: {icon: 'fa fa-circle-o'}
            },
            radio: {
                on: {icon: 'fa fa-dot-circle-o'},
                off: {icon: 'fa fa-circle-o'}
            }
        };

        $widget.prepend('<span class="' + settings[type].off.icon + '"></span>');

        $widget.on('click', function () {
            $input.prop('checked', !$input.is(':checked'));

            updateDisplay();
        });

        function updateDisplay() {
            var isChecked = $input.is(':checked') ? 'on' : 'off';

            $widget.find('.fa').attr('class', settings[type][isChecked].icon);

        }

        updateDisplay();
    });
});
```

I'm changing the checkbox value with this:

```
if (result.status) {
    $("#statusedit").prop("checked", true);
} else {
    $("#statusedit").prop("checked", false);
}
```

Just calling `updatedisplay()` is not working.

P.S.: The checkbox value is changing but the icon is the same.